# WIFI not working Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

WIFI not working on my laptop. I have a ryzen 7000 series. When I run this command (lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
) I get this result below:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek 
Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [] (rev ff)
DeviceName: Realtek Wireless LAN + BT
Kernel driver in use: rtw89_8852be
Kernel modules: rtw_8852be
```

Comment: Your output shows that your system recogniized the card, and loaded the `rtw_8852be` driver to handle it. Please be more specific than "not working". Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep 8852` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.